# Regex - Prevent pasting in an input

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I have regex expression, which prevented me entering certain characters in the input field

```
onKeyMonitor ($event) {
      const value = $event.key;
      const pattern = /^[@$^<>[\]{}]*$/;
      const regex = new RegExp(pattern);
      if (regex.test(value)) {
        $event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

But this is failing if I paste the same special characters, What needs to be done here.
I have written an onpaste event as well. with similar logic, but it is failing.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to use code block on SO.

Comment: Create classes according to your json and use newtonsoft api for deserialization of your json string into those newly created classes. Its simple and easy approach.

Comment: @l_raffa, JPBlanc, Sachila Ranawaka  ,Jakob Christensen, greg-449To All Who marked as duplicate could you please provide the original link.  It should not be  the usual json deserialistation, I have asked for deserialising array elements. Please provide the link of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially you could define the following classes:

```
public class AnswerOption
{

    [JsonProperty("parentQuestion")]
    public string ParentQuestion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parentAnswer")]
    public object ParentAnswer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("answerOption")]
    public object Option { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{

    [JsonProperty("questionId")]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("questionName")]
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("questionType")]
    public string QuestionType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("questionSequenceNumber")]
    public int QuestionSequenceNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pageNo")]
    public int PageNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("highlightedText")]
    public string HighlightedText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isDynamicText")]
    public string IsDynamicText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("answerOptions")]
    public IList<AnswerOption> AnswerOptions { get; set; }
}

public class DataObj
{

    [JsonProperty("surveyId")]
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("questions")]
    public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    [JsonProperty("dataObj")]
    public DataObj DataObj { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("errorCode")]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("errorMessage")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could deserialize your json as below:

```
var example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json);
```

where `json` is a variable that holds the json you want to deserialize.

Last you could access the firsts question id as below:

```
labl1.text = example.DataObj?.Questions?.FirstOrDefault()?.QuestionId;
```

Comment: Thank you,I have done that too forgot to add it in the question.

Comment: @tony.g you are welcome. Please check my upadte.

Comment: The problem is after creating the class,i am still unable to deserialise the array values. Any code snippet sample to parse array elements.?

Comment: @tony.g Please declare the above classes and deserialize the json as in the line where `example` is declared. Then make the assignement: `labl1.text = example.DataObj?.Questions?.FirstOrDefault()?.QuestionId;` and let me know thanks.

Comment: Thank you it is working. the json is for creating dynamic feedback. Based on the answer of previous question your next question will be different. Is there anyway i can do this in front end itslef. You are the only person to answer my question as I searched in multiple blogs and nowhere i can see this answer. –

Answer (score 0):

Use this website to help you generate C# classes from Json string http://json2csharp.com/

Note: Don't forget to double the data type.